# Is it possible to have an critical section algorithm that does NOT SATISFY BOUNDED WAITING and satisfies only mutual exclusion and progress?

Tags: multithreading, semaphore, critical-section

I've been reading about critical section problem and I cannot simply understand the following lines

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)

> A critical section will usually terminate in fixed time, and a thread,
>   task, or process will have to wait for a fixed time to enter it (aka
>   bounded waiting)

[Uregina](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hamilton/courses/330/notes/synchro/node2.html) (Similar to the definition found on the [Galvin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720))

> there must exist a bound on the number of times that other processes
>   are allowed to enter their critical sections after a process has made
>   a request to enter its critical section and before that request is
>   granted

**They all have the below peterson's solution provide bounded waiting ? There is no count variable to indicate the number of times a process enters critical section ? How can we satisfy the bounded waiting condition in this case ? I couldn't find any algorithm which violates only bounded waiting, can some one show one ?**

```
bool flag[0]   = false;
bool flag[1]   = false;
int turn;
P0:      flag[0] = true;
P0_gate: turn = 1;
         while (flag[1] && turn == 1);
         // critical section
         ...
         flag[0] = false;
         // remainder section
```